# Centering Content in Two Side-by-Side Divs

Tags: html, css

Trying to center content within each of the two side-by-side divs.

Not sure why my content within each of these divs seems to center towards each other.

I have built a main container and two divs within it. The text is center aligned but not sure how to center the content inside of the divs.

Any ideas?

[image]

```css
.div-header-seller-resources{
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:32px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.div-detail-seller-resources{
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
}
.div-main-container-seller-resources{
    width:100%;
}
.div-main-container-seller-resources{
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.div-seller-resources-left{
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    text-align:center;
}
.div-seller-resources-right{
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    text-align:center;
}
.seller-resources-height{
    height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-main-container-seller-resources">
    <div class="div-seller-resources-left" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="seller-resources-height">
            <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/how-yodega-works/">How Yodega Works</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Learn about how Yodega works for sellers</div>
          </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="seller-resources-height">
            <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/referrals/">Referrals</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Refer another business to reduce your fees</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
         <div class="seller-resources-height">
                <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/how-to-sell-with-yodega/">How to Sell with Yodega</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Learn the best ways to promote your Yodega store</div>
         </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-seller-resources-right" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="seller-resources-height">
            <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/setting-up-your-store/">Setting Up Your Store</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Detailed instructions on how to build your store</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="seller-resources-height">
            <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/advanced-product-shipping/">Advanced Shipping &amp; Product Options</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Variable Shipping Costs, Add Product Details and More</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="seller-resources-height">
            <div class="div-header-seller-resources"><a href="https://yodega.com/order-management-seller-dashboard/">Order Management, Seller Dashboard &amp; Payment</a></div>
            <div class="div-detail-seller-resources">Detailed information on how to manage and fill orders and payments</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="seller-overview-button-container">
<a href="http://yodega.com/sell"><button id="button2" type="button contact-button">Seller Overview</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: i think its already in center??

Comment: you can give css to the parent class ```text-center``` and for your inside or child div use ```margin:0px auto```

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. That worked - I don't understand why, but it did! :)

Thanks!

Comment: ok i am adding the ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more outer container div and add this rule.

```
.container{
display:flex;
Justify-content:center;
}
```

And inner div

```
.inner {
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
```

And the structure will be(this is pug)

```
div(class="container ")
    div(class=" inner")
        div my_left
        div my_right
```

Set width of left and right div.

Comment: This works great, thank you. Any thoughts on how to make this more responsive? As is, the right div doesn't fall under the left div, and the words overlap on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can give CSS to the parent class `text-center` and for your inside or child div use `margin:0px auto;`.
This will result making your each child element center inside the div.